# @IBInspectable NSLayoutConstraint doesn't work Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a strange behaviour, constraints do not want to be updated in Interface Builder.

Here are 2 variants of my code and both don't work.

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var preciseConstant: CGFloat {
        get {
            return constant * UIScreen.main.scale
        }
        set {
            constant = CGFloat(newValue) / UIScreen.main.scale
        }
    }
}

@IBDesignable class CustomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    @IBInspectable var screenHeight: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            changeContraint()
        }
    }

    func changeContraint() {
        self.constant = self.screenHeight / UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there  my mistake or it's bug Xcode?

Comment: I have the same question @tikhonov

Answer (score 0):

When you use `IBInspectable` properties, your `didSet` logic don't work. All you need to do is change needed properties (like `self.constant`) in `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: No, it works. For example.`@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var backColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = backColor
        }
    }
}`